# Creating an HTML report with embedded screenshots of failed JUnit tests

Tags: html, maven, report, screenshot

I've put together a custom JUnit runner that saves a screenshot when a WebDriver test fails.
I'm using Maven's failsafe plugin to create reports of the integration tests and TeamCity is our CI server.

I know TeamCity supports custom reports, but I don't know how I'd embed the image files into an HTML page (or pages) with references to the relevant tests.

What would be a good method to integrate the screenshots into the test report? 
Is there a Maven plugin that'll do the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [Allure-report](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki) would suit for your purpose. It allows to create a nice report that contains different attachments, including screenshots. Moreover it has [JUnit integration](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit) and [Teamcity plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity-plugin), so it fully covers your use-case.

Comment: Can someone confirm this works?  
Unfortunately, I am no longer working on that project (it's been two years) and currently have no access to and environment with JUnit and Teamcity, so I cannot confirm if Allure would do the job or not.
If someone else can confirm that it works, I'd be glad to accept this answer as it has already earned 2 upvotes in tow days.

Comment: Hi, I can confirm that it works not only with JUnit but also with TestNG. A new version 1.4.0 is being actively developed right now but there's also a stable branch 1.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to simply change the reports cause they are generated by the [maven-report-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) which can't be simply changed.
What you can try is to create a separate folder and create a link via the site.xml descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [maven-cobertura-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/). Including this in your build will generate a HTML report of all the test case success, failure and coverage. Hope this helps....

Comment: Your given link is not working. please update in answer.