# Possible to add screenshot to JUnit test xml files?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver, allure

Is it possible to add screenshot to JUnit test xml files?

For example, if one of my tests fail the method will be indicated inside the XML file as a failure. Is it possible to attach a screenshot link or the screenshot itself when a test fails?

Comment: Check out this question, not sure if this is a duplicate, since you're already using allure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155853/creating-an-html-report-with-embedded-screenshots-of-failed-junit-tests